# prevent php dropdown from getting reset after submit

Tags: php, laravel-4, get

Hi i am developing an laravel application and i have a form like shown below

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h3 style="margin-left: -23px!important;">@lang('general.calculate_2014')</h3>
</div>


<div class="row form-wrapper">
   <form class="form-horizontal"   method="get" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('years') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
               <label for="years" class="col-md-3 control-label calculate-label">@lang('admin/calculate2014/form.Calculate_dep')</label>
               <?php
                    global $Year;
                    $years = array();
                    for ($i = 2014; $i < 2050; $i++)
                    {
                      $years[] = $i;
                    } 

                    echo '<select name="Year" class="controls assettext select2 selectyear" id="Year" >';
                    echo '<option value=""> -- Select Year -- </option>';
                    foreach($years as $option)
                    {
                        echo "<option value='{$option}' >{$option}</option>";   
                    }  
                    echo "</select>";

               ?>
                   <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-flat gray gobtn" id ="nextHide" value="Next" /> 

                    <?php
                        if($_GET)
                        { 
                           echo '<b style="color:red"> Click View Details For the Selected Year:&nbsp;'.$_GET['Year'].'</b>';
                           $Year =$_GET['Year'];
                        }           
                    ?>   
                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-flat gray viewbtn" name="go" id="go" value="View Details" />
                   <div  class="display-summary" style="margin:70px 0px 0px -342px;"> </div>

                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat green pull-right proceedhide" id="proceed" value="proceed" onclick="CompanyDepreciationCalculation()"> Proceed </button>  
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#go").click(function(){
            $('.display-summary').html("<?php
            FinancialYearCalculationSummary($Year); 
            ?>"); 

        });         
    });     

</script>
```

Here i am trying to pass a value from dropdown and get the passed value and pass it to a function called FinancialYearCalculationSummary,on clicking the next button.The value gets passed through url and again the dropdown value gets refreshed.

How do i avoid the dropdown from being refreshed after the php page getting submitted.I tried the possible duplicate of this question but none of them worked.

Please help me to achieve this......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($years as $option)
{
    echo "<option value='{$option}'";
    if (isset($_GET['Year'])) { if ($_GET['Year'] == $option) { echo 'selected'; } }
    echo ">{$option}</option>";   
}
```

Only change this part.

This avoid to refresh the select.

Hope works for you.

Comment: your solution worked like charm,you saved my day thankyou so much accepted your answer...........

Comment: I have one more conflict in same page.As mentioned In my code i try to pass the selected dropdown variable to a function called FinancialYearCalculationSummary in my script but the problem is that as soon as the function is executed it gets disappeared, how to avoid it from being disappeared.I know calling a php function like this is not a good practice but i couldn't succeed by using ajax.Hope u can help me to solve this

Comment: Im not sure what is your other problem but you are not calling jquery, add this to your page: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>` Once you add this, the script works and the button is disabled when you click 'View Details'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply my exact problem is to pass the selected year value as a parameter to a function named FinancialYearCalculationSummary as mentioned above in my code, Inside the function i have some echo statements, now the year gets passed correctly but the problem is the echo statement gets executed once and disappears and works again and the process continues, how to prevent the echo statement from being disappeared so that it stays staticly after button click.

Comment: I'm not understand very well whats is your problem, the $Year variable is always available in the script, you can add `console.log(<?php echo $Year; ?>)` to view how the variable moves.